# Identity of Binomial sum

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I found this identity recently when I was trying to find a formula for a trace of power of $2\times 2$ matrices,
\begin{align*}
n \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{2n - k} {2n - k, \choose k} x^k y^{2n - 2k} = \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \sum_{k =0}^n {2n\choose 2k} y^{2k} (y^2 - 4x)^{n - k}. 
\end{align*}
Both sides equal to half of trace of a matrix with determinant $x$ and trace $y$.

I have tried expanding the $y^2 - 4x$ using binomial identity and got
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{2^{2n}}  \sum_{k = 0}^n {2n\choose 2k} y^{2k} \sum_{m = 0}^{n - k}{n - k\choose m}(-1)^m(4x)^m y^{2n - 2k - 2m}
\\
&= \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \sum_{k = 0}^n \sum_{m = 0}^{n - k} {2n \choose 2k}{n - k\choose m}(-1)^m (4x)^m y^{2n - 2m}
\end{align*} 
This is where I got stuck. Any idea?

Update: I tried to expand the last form,
\begin{align*} 
\frac{1}{2^{2n}}&\Bigg[\sum_{m = 0}^n {2n\choose 0}{n\choose m}(-1)^m(4x)^my^{2n - 2m}\\ 
+&\sum_{m = 0}^{n - 1} {2n\choose 2}{n - 1\choose m}(-1)^m(4x)^my^{2n - 2m}\\
+&\sum_{m = 0}^{n - 2} {2n\choose 4}{n - 2\choose m}(-1)^m(4x)^my^{2n - 2m}\\
+&\vdots\\
+&\sum_{m = 0}^{n - n} {2n\choose 2n}{n - n\choose m}(-1)^m(4x)^my^{2n - 2m}\Bigg],
\end{align*}
and got that the coefficient of $x^k y^{2n - 2k}$ in above expression is just
$$\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\sum_{m = 0}^{n - k}{2n\choose 2m}{n - m\choose k} (-1)^k 4^k.$$
This left me with proving that $$\frac{n}{2n - k} {2n - k\choose k} =\sum_{m = 0}^{n - k}{2n\choose 2m}{n - m\choose k} 2^{2k - 2n}.$$
Again, I got stuck at this point. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We seek to show that

$$n\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{2n-k} {2n-k\choose k} x^k y^{2n-2k}
= \frac{1}{2^{2n}} 
\sum_{k=0}^n {2n\choose 2k} y^{2k} (y^2-4x)^{n-k}.$$

We compare  the coefficient on  $[x^q]$ of the  LHS and the  RHS where
$0\le q\le  n$ and show  that they are  equal. We must  therefore show
that

$$n \frac{(-1)^q}{2n-q} {2n-q\choose q} y^{2n-2q}
= [x^q] \frac{1}{2^{2n}} 
\sum_{k=0}^n {2n\choose 2k} y^{2k} (y^2-4x)^{n-k}.$$

The RHS is

$$[x^q] \frac{1}{2^{2n}} 
\sum_{k=0}^n {2n\choose 2n-2k} y^{2n-2k} (y^2-4x)^{k}
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{2n}} 
\sum_{k=q}^n {2n\choose 2n-2k} y^{2n-2k} 
[x^q] (y^2-4x)^{k}
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{2n}} 
\sum_{k=q}^n {2n\choose 2k} y^{2n-2k} 
{k\choose q} (-4)^q y^{2k-2q}
\\ = y^{2n-2q}  \frac{1}{2^{2n}} 
\sum_{k=q}^n {2n\choose 2k} 
{k\choose q} (-4)^q.$$

We have reduced the claim to

$$n \frac{(-1)^q}{2n-q} {2n-q\choose q} =
\frac{1}{2^{2n}} 
\sum_{k=q}^n {2n\choose 2k} 
{k\choose q} (-4)^q.$$

The RHS is

$$\frac{1}{2^{2n}} 
\sum_{k=q}^n 
{k\choose q} (-4)^q [z^{2n-2k}] (1+z)^{2n}
\\ = \frac{(-1)^q}{2^{2n-2q}} [z^{2n}] (1+z)^{2n}
\sum_{k=q}^n {k\choose q}  z^{2k}.$$

Now when $k$ exceeds $n$ we get zero from the coefficient extractor,
which enforces the range:

$$\frac{(-1)^q}{2^{2n-2q}} [z^{2n}] (1+z)^{2n}
\sum_{k\ge q} {k\choose q}  z^{2k}
\\ = \frac{(-1)^q}{2^{2n-2q}} [z^{2n}] z^{2q} (1+z)^{2n}
\sum_{k\ge 0} {k+q\choose q} z^{2k}
\\ = \frac{(-1)^q}{2^{2n-2q}} [z^{2n}] z^{2q} (1+z)^{2n}
\frac{1}{(1-z^2)^{q+1}}
\\ = \frac{(-1)^q}{2^{2n-2q}} [z^{2n-2q}] (1+z)^{2n-q-1}
\frac{1}{(1-z)^{q+1}}
\\ = \frac{(-1)^q}{2^{2n-2q}}
\sum_{p=0}^{2n-q-1} {2n-q-1\choose p} {2n-2q-p+q\choose q}
\\ = \frac{(-1)^q}{2^{2n-2q}}
\sum_{p=0}^{2n-q-1} {2n-q-1\choose 2n-q-1-p} 
{2n-q-p\choose q}.$$

Then we have

$${2n-q-1\choose 2n-q-1-p} {2n-q-p\choose q}
= \frac{(2n-q-1)! (2n-q-p)}{p! \times q! \times (2n-2q-p)!}
\\ = \frac{1}{2n-q} \frac{(2n-q)! (2n-q-p)}
{p! \times q! \times (2n-2q-p)!}
\\ = \frac{1}{2n-q} {2n-q\choose q} {2n-2q\choose p}
(2n-q-p).$$

Substituting we  find (here we  have included the value  for $p=2n-q$,
which is zero):

$$\frac{(-1)^q}{2^{2n-2q}} \frac{1}{2n-q} {2n-q\choose q}
\sum_{p=0}^{2n-q} {2n-2q\choose p}
(2n-q-p).$$

Working with the  remaining sum we note  that $(2n-2q)^\underline{p} =
0$ when $p\gt 2n-2q$ and $2n-q\ge 2n-2q$ so we may continue with

$$\sum_{p=0}^{2n-2q} {2n-2q\choose p} (2n-q-p)
= (2n-q) 2^{2n-2q}
-  \sum_{p=1}^{2n-2q} {2n-2q\choose p} p
\\ = (2n-q) 2^{2n-2q}
- (2n-2q) \sum_{p=1}^{2n-2q} {2n-2q - 1\choose p-1}
\\ = (2n-q) 2^{2n-2q} - (2n-2q) 2^{2n-2q-1}
= (2n-q) 2^{2n-2q} - (n-q) 2^{2n-2q}
\\ = n 2^{2n-2q}.$$

Substituting we at last obtain

$$n \frac{(-1)^q}{2n-q} {2n-q\choose q}$$

which was to be shown.